# NSIS nsExec path issue perhaps

Tags: node.js, windows, windows-installer, nsis

First time with making an installation file. Using NSIS. Trying to run a nodeJS script command line after installation completes and poking about online suggestions all seem to be a variation of

> Section "runNodeJavascript"
> nsExec::Exec '"$SYSDIR\cmd.exe" /c
> node "c:\Program Files (x86)\FolderOne\FolderTwo\JavascriptToRun.js"'
> SectionEnd

But my experimentation so far is for naught, any insight? Everything else with NSIS online has been pretty helpful making a little installer but for some reason hitting a little barrier here...

Comment: That call assumes node.exe/bat is in %path%. Use a full path if you know it.

Comment: That was indeed the problem, thank you. Switched "node" to C:\"Program Files"\nodejs\node.exe and that works.